# Error in NCOL(X): object 'wages' not found calls: <anonymous>

Tags: knitr

I'm trying to knit my code but this message comes up. everything ran fine but when I try to knit there is an error. (I'm new to r)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P1oH.png)

Comment: Could you add your code here instead of an image?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.